# How can I find the second parent of a searched commit in git?

Tags: git

In git, you can use regex to find the last merge commit:

`git show :/^Merge`

However, I want to find the second parent of that commit, but I can't seem to find a way for it to work:

`git show :/^Merge/^2`

Is there any syntax that would allow me to do this?

My ultimate goal is to set an alias similar to:

`git diff :/^Merge/^2..HEAD`

This will let me see the diff from my feature branch to master easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like `:/<text>` syntax is equivalent to `HEAD^{/<text>}`.  Now that we have a line ending to delimit the revision specification, we can continue:

```
HEAD^{/<text>}^2
```

Seems like it works, after an initial test on my local branch

Comment: Thanks! the following command actually works: `git diff HEAD^{/^Merge}^2..HEAD`
*Very* useful.

Comment: The following command gives the same result, though you'll have to specify the parent branch: `git diff $(git merge-base origin/master HEAD)..HEAD`

Comment: To be precise, `:/<text>` is _not_ equivalent to `HEAD^{/<text>}`. The first form searches among the commits reachable from any ref, including HEAD. The second one -- among the commits reachable from the specified ref (`HEAD` in this case). But in boundaries of the question's topic, it looks acceptable.